# .NET System.OutOfMemoryException and AppDomains

Tags: ado.net, appdomain, out-of-memory

I have a plugin manager that launches a plugin which connects to a FoxPro 
database through the ADO.NET OLE DB provider.

At one client site connections are opened and closed without any problems 
but at another client site, it gets stuck in 'connection.Open();' and within 
a couple of seconds over 1GB of memory is allocated.

Within one minute after that another 1GB is allocated and 
System.OutOfMemoryException is thrown.

The plugin manager unloads the AppDomain and continues.

Where would I start debugging this?

Answer (score 3):

Enable 'debug external code' hrough the Debug options and then step through to the code in question and watch what it does. You might be able to use a memory profiler (I like DotTrace) to build a clearer picture of what is slowing it down.

Comment: Thanks. 

Is there something free like DotTrace?

I took the code out of the plugin and put it into a new console app on the same machine and it runs fine. Perhaps something to do with running in another AppDomain, though this same utility runs at another site fine...

Comment: If there is and it's anywhere near a good, please let me know ;) DotTrace has a trial though and is cheaper if you buy it for just one language IIRC.

That certainly sounds like the right kind of track...